# Задача на с++ по бинарному поиску

Tags: c++, алгоритм, олимпиада, бинарный-поиск

## C. Веревочки

ограничение по времени на тест: 1 секунда

ограничение по памяти на тест: 256 мегабайт

ввод: стандартный ввод

вывод: стандартный вывод

С утра шел дождь, и ничего не предвещало беды. Но к обеду выглянуло солнце, и в лагерь заглянула СЭС. Пройдя по всем домикам и корпусам, СЭС вынесла следующий вердикт: бельевые веревки в жилых домиках не удовлетворяют нормам СЭС. Как выяснилось, в каждом домике должно быть ровно по одной бельевой веревке, и все веревки должны иметь одинаковую длину. В лагере имеется *n* бельевых веревок и *k* домиков. Чтобы лагерь не закрыли, требуется так нарезать данные веревки, чтобы среди получившихся веревочек было *k* одинаковой длины. Размер штрафа обратно пропорционален длине бельевых веревок, которые будут развешены в домиках. Поэтому начальство лагеря стремиться максимизировать длину этих веревочек.

### Входные данные

В первой строке заданы два числа – *n* и *k* (*1 ≤ n, k ≤ 10001*). Далее в каждой из последующих *n* строк записано по одному числу *a<sub>i</sub>* (*1 ≤ a<sub>i</sub> ≤ 10<sup>8</sup>*)  – длине *i*-й бельевой веревки. Длина веревки задана в сантиметрах. Все длины лежат в интервале от 1 сантиметра до 100 километров включительно.

### Выходные данные

В выходной файл следует вывести одно целое число — максимальную длину веревочек, удовлетворяющую условию, в сантиметрах. В случае, если лагерь закроют, выведите 0.

### Пример:

входные данные

> ```
> 4 11
> 802
> 743
> 457
> 539
> ```

выходные данные

> ```
> 200
> ```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    vector<int> a(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    int l = 0;
    int r = *max_element(a.begin(), a.end());
    while (r > l + 1) {
        int m = (l + r) / 2;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int x : a){
            sum += x / m;
        }
        if (sum < k) {
            r = m;
        } else {
            l = m;
        }
    }
    cout << l << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

написал вот такой код, но выдает ошибку на 5 тесте.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Попробуйте тест n = k = 1, a = [1].